# Updating Field from plugin

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

So i'm trying to update a checkbox field using a custom plugin i built. I have three tiers on my site, tier one that you only get access to certain items, tier two you get access to tier one and other additional assets and tier three you get access to everything in both tier 1, 2 and 3.

When you sign up for tier two (while being signed in) the form i have shows the currentUser info already filled into the form. The only item NOT filled is a checkbox that is a terms of use, each form has a different terms of use.

I need to be able to view the user and what Terms of Use they have accepted.